# comparing values of textfields with values rendered by a function (not working)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a function that renders 2 columns: date and time for upcoming appointments. 
When the user enter date and time in the textfields, I want to avoid conflict time, so I want to compare those values with values of dates and times rendered by the function. If he entered date and time similar to a record from the rendered function, I want to show a toast message to tell him to change the date and time since this appointment is booked.

Here is my code that I inserted in the OnCreateView of the class that extends fragment :

```
Cursor res = myDB.getUpcomAp();

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while (res.moveToNext()){

if( (res.getString(0)).equals(chosdate.getText().toString())&&(res.getString(1)).equals(chostime.getText().toString()))

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This appointment is booked, please choose another one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


};
```

But nothing is rendered when the user choose the same date and time of a booked appointment. Please help

Comment: when running while loop, are you able to get all the date and time values ?

Comment: am using while (res.moveToNext()) and here is the function: public Cursor getUpcomAp ( ) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor res = db.rawQuery ( " select dateap,time from " + TABLE_NAME2 + "  where date (dateap) > date ('now') order by date(dateap),time asc " , null );
  return res;

Comment: I am asking to print value of res.getString(0) and res.getString(1) in the while loop. Is this prints all the table data ?

Comment: u mean it should be like this StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while (res.moveToNext()){
buffer.append("Date:"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
        buffer.append("Time:"+res.getString(1)+"\n\n");
        
  
if( (res.getString(0)).equals(chosdate.getText().toString())&&(res.getString(1)).equals(chostime.getText().toString()))

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This appointment is booked, please choose another one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


};

Comment: No. i just meant you to debug whether you are getting values in the while loop or not.

Answer (score 0):

i solve it using addTextChangedListener.
thank you